# proc_open runs too long in windows 7

Tags: php, proc-open, elfinder

I am using [elfinder 2.0](http://elfinder.org/), but it doesn't work in Windows 7. The reason is that the `proc_open()` function takes too long to execute. For example, a simple command such as `tar --version` executes 25 seconds with `proc_open()`. 
Here is this code:

```
$command = 'tar --version';
$descriptorspec = array(
    array('pipe', 'r'),
    array('pipe', 'w'),
    array('pipe', 'w'),
);
$pipes = null;
$process = proc_open($command, $descriptorspec, $pipes, null, null);
```

How can I resolve the problem?

Comment: Cannot really believe this. show an (simple) example that takes 25 seconds.

Comment: I would analyze syscalls using [wintrc](http://sourceforge.net/projects/wintrc/)